# camel: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am developing a spring-camel application. My beans.xml looks like below.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">



</beans>
```

When I launching the application, I am end up in below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]
Offending resource: class path resource [beans.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:621)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.sample.app.Application.main(Application.java:10)
```

I added 'camel-core', camel-spring' library in my maven dependency. Since these are added as maven dependency, I can confirm that the camel-spring library is in my classpath.

Reference links.
[Apache Camel Spring configuration error - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504163/apache-camel-spring-configuration-error-unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandl)

http://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-manual-2.6.0.html